Definition of a reflexive Banach Space
I am a little bit confused about the Definition of "reflexive" in "Methods of modern Mathematical Physics" by Micheal Reed and Barry Simon. A prior Definition states:
"A bounded linear operator from a normed linear space X to a normed linear space Y is called an isomorphism if it is a bijection which is continuous and which has a continuous inverse. If it is norm preserving, it is called an isometric isomorphism."
My Problem is now with Theorem III.4 and the Definition in this Picture:
From Theorem III.4 follows, that J is an isometric isomorphism and therefore an bijection and therefore surjective. So every J in Theorem III.4 should be surjective and X of every J should be reflexive. For what is the definition of "relexive" needed?
Where is my error?
Thank you for answers!

In Theorem III.4 it is stated that $J$ is an isometric isomorphism of $X$ onto a possibly proper subspace of $X^{**}$. So, Theorem does not state that $J$ is surjective and for some Banach spaces it is not. If it is then $X$ is called reflexive.

@Matsmir I think it would be nice to have your comment as an answer.

@SeverinSchraven On the one hand it seems to provide a complete answer to the question. On the other hand it is just a rewritten theorem from Reed&Simon with a highlighted part.

@Matsmir It's very nicely written and highlights were the misconception is.

@Matsmir And I feel that this whole business is very confusing for a lot of people when they see it the first time. Seems like a valuable answer to me :)
